# Bellman-Ford - is number of interations greater than diameter?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

> Diameter of a connected, undirected graph is the smallest natural
>   number *d*, so that between any two vertices of the graph exist path
>   of length at most *d*.
>
> Prove or disprove: in Bellman-Ford is the number of iterations always
>   equal or lower than *d*.

I'm trying to solve this issue. What I tried was sketching a lot of graphs, however I have failed to find a single graph where the number of iterations would be higher than the diameter.

The only graph where the number of iterations wouldn't be <= than diameter would be a graph with negative edges, however I found out that in undirected graph there can't be any negative edges, otherwhere there would be a negative cycle.

So, AFAIK the statement is correct. However, how would I prove such a statement? I don't even know how to start. Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the length of a path when you define *diameter*? Is it the sum of the weights of the edges on the path, or the number of edges on the path?

Comment: @xskxzr It's path,  so it's the sum of the weights of the edges on the path.

Comment: What if the weights are very small so that $d=1$?

Comment: @xskxzr If the smallest path between any two vertices is 1, then *d=1*

Comment: Given the context of this question (and that it is about Bellman Ford), I would imagine the diameter its referring to is the _number of edges_ on the longest shortest path. Consider a linked list of 5 nodes where each edge has weight 0.5 (nothing says this can't be the case). Then the diameter according to your definition is 2. However, Bellman-Ford will run 4 iterations in worst case. I would double check how your instructor is defining _diameter_ because I doubt it is sum of edge weights in this context. The distinction to be concerned about is path _length_ vs. path _weight_.

Comment: "I found out that in undirected graph there can't be any negative edges". Consider the graph with two nodes $v_1$ and $v_2$ with one edge $v_1v_2$ of weight -1.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Undirected edge of weight -1 is both |V1V2| and |V2V1|, so there's already a negative cycle.

Comment: @ryan Yes, I'm aware that's it's not formulated clearly and I'm also unsure what they mean by diameter, that was just my understanding. But I think we solved the problem either way, it's either true for the number of edges (with a proof by Yuval Filmus), or it's false for the sum of weights, with the counterexample you provided. Thanks! This is a recurring test question and I have been stuck on it for weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Bellman–Ford algorithm, after $t$ iterations the array contains, for any two nodes, the minimal walk of length at most $t$ connecting them. Assuming your graph doesn't have negative weights, the shortest walk between any two vertices will be a path, and so its length would be at most the diameter. Therefore there is no need to run the algorithm beyond $d$ iterations.

Comment: There is a subtle nuance, that there is _no need_ to run the algorithm beyond $d$ iterations. However, the [prototypical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Algorithm) of the algorithm is to naively run $|V| - 1$ iterations, so it ultimately depends on implementation as to whether or not it runs at most $d$ iterations.